# Project a single array item mongodb C#

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I have the following json

```
{
   "name":"Student",
    "Classes" : ["Chemistry","Math","Algebra"]
 }
```

and the following poco

```
public class Studen
{
     public string Name {get;set;}
     public string[] Classes {get; set;}
}
```

I want to query a specific student that takes a specific class (say Math), and the poco to have a single item in the array which is the "Math" string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if your collection is a variable collection:

```
collection.Find(x => x.Classes.Contains("Math"))
          .Project(s => 
                   new Student {
                        Name = s.Name,
                        Classes = s.Classes.Where(c=>c=="Math").ToArray()})
         .ToList();
```